# Need to clarify whether this makes use of typedef

Tags: c++, c

I'm using a library called TinyGPS for a Arduino project. The code has following line.

```
 TinyGPS gps;
```

Is this a typedef or if not, can you explain what is is...

```
TinyGPS gps;
static char dtostrfbuffer[20];
int CS = 53;
int LED = 13;
```

Comment: `TinyGPS` is a type. It shouldn't matter whether it's a typedef or some other form of defining a type. `gps` is a variable.

Comment: Don't you have appropriate library documentation to read?

Comment: I always find `grep TinyGPS $(find . -name \*.h)` very helpful to answer those questions, so helpful, that I usually encapsulate something along these lines into a script, so that I can easily grep for anything within a project with a simple command.

Comment: @cmaster, that's a good tip.  [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) for example, can already do that with the `--hh` flag, e.g. `ack --hh TinyGPS`.

Comment: @CarlNorum I didn't know about `ack`, but it looks like I need to check it out. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

If it's C, it's either a `typedef` or `#defined` to some other type.   If it's C++, it could also be a class, struct, or union.

Check the output of the preprocessor to figure out which it is, or just grep around your headers until you find it.

Comment: OP's tags say "C" and "C++", so I was just trying to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a typedef, but it could also be a struct, class or union. The library documentation will tell you what it is and how to use it.

Comment: And formally: `struct`, `class` and `union` are all keywords which define a class.